# How does AWS reduce the latency?

Tags: amazon-web-services

My company is in Vietnam. And the nearest AWS region is Singapore. The thing is most of our users are from Vietnam and We want the latency of the requests to our servers is as low as possible.

In paper If we use a hosting service from Vietnam the latency will be lower, due to the distance is shorter.

What are AWS's solutions to reduce the latency? Do they cooperate with local internet vendor to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you mean you are already using AWS with server in singapore and you experience very low latency? and you are seeking what's the secret behind? *OR* You are asking what is Amazon roadmap to make it faster for vietnam customer in the future?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is out of AWS's coverage/scope. You're probably better off finding a local provider in Vietnam as it's not just about Internet connection.

Comment: @YouQi  I mean Amazon roadmap to make it faster for Vietnam customer in the future

Comment: unless there are big demands/customers in Vietnam with well established infrastructures in place, I doubt setting a node in the country is a priority for amazon. Singapore should serve well for the region.

Answer (score 1):

The major option available from Vietnam to reduce latency, is to use AWS Direct Connect.

Though its not significant, while having network traffic routed through AWS Global Network Backbone, the number of hops and packet loss is less.

However, there is a significant upfront commitment in setting up AWS Direct Connect.